# How to use jsGrid using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jqgrid

I was working with flask and i want to use a jqGrid view, here is the code for loading data.

```
        controller: {
                loadData: function(filter) {
                    var d = $.Deferred();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/dashboard",
                        data: filter,
                        dataType: "JSON"
                    }).done(function(result) {
                      d.resolve($.map(result, function(item) {
                         return $.extend(item.fields, { id: item.pk });
                     }));
                    });
                    return d.promise();
                }},

   Here is the .py File

   @app.route("/dashboard")
   @is_logged_in
   def dashboard():

    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()

    result=cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles")
    articles=cur.fetchall()
    name=json.dumps(articles)
    if result>0:
     return render_template("dashboard.html",articles=articles,name=name)
   else:
     msg="No Article Found"
     return render_template("dashboard.html",msg=msg)
  cur.close()
```

but the grid is empty, how could i accomplish this.

Comment: include the flask view code in the question

Comment: Do you mean the .py file?

Answer (score 0):

First, factor out your query.

```
def query_articles():
  with mysql.connection.cursor() as cur:
    query = "SELECT * FROM articles"
    cur.execute(query)
    articles = cur.fetchall()
  return articles
```

Make a view function for an endpoint that returns articles as `JSON`.

```
@app.route("/api/articles", methods=['GET'])
def articles():
     return jsonify(query_articles())
```

You can use this endpoint in your AJAX request.

```
controller: ...
    url: "/api/articles",
```

**Another way** is to make a `div` node in your template to contain the serialized list of articles.

You can use this `div` in `controller` to make the grid.

main.py:

```
from flask import jsonify
from json import dumps



@app.route("/dashboard", methods=['GET'])
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
    articles = query_articles()
    if len(articles) > 0:
      return render_template(
        "dashboard.html", 
        articles=articles
      )
    return render_template("dashboard.html", msg="No Article Found")
```

template.html:
    ...
    
    ...

script.js:

```
var articles = JSON.parse($('#dataSource').data('articles'));
var articles = articles.map(function(item) {
                return Object.assign({}, item.fields, { id: item.pk });
              });
controller: {
  data: articles
},
```